# Create new variables from a list that does not exist in current dataset in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create new variables taken from a list of 11 variables, that do not exist in current dataset (in order to have all my datasets have the same dimension and be able to "cbind" them).

Here is what I have tried to do (sorry it is really inefficient I know, I am new to R - there might be better ways of doing it):

```
DataInd <- list()
listInd <- list("SDGFPALL","WHS4_154","WHS4_100","WHS4_106","TB_1","HIV_ARTCOVERAGE","MDG_0000000013",
                "WSH_SANITATION_BASIC","BP_04","NCD_GLUC_04","TOBACCO_0000000192","WHS6_102","HWF_0001",
                "HRH_41","MH_6","SDGIHR2018","SDGIHR")

Labels <- list("year","region","country","gho","publishstate","value","worldbankincomegroup","residenceareatype","datasource","agegroup","sex")

for (k in 1:length(listInd)){
  print(k)
  Ind_name <- listInd[k]
  df <- get_data(Ind_name)
  listvar <- list(colnames(df))
  for (m in 1:length(Labels)){
    if(!(Labels[[m]] %in% colnames(df))){
      Var <- paste0("df$",Labels[m])
      Var <- NA
    }
  }
  DataInd[[length(DataInd)+1]] <- df
}

DataAll <- do.call(rbind,DataInd)
```

The "Var" does not work. I have not managed to find a way to allocate NA to new variables that need to be created from a list.

Maybe merging an empty dataset with the 11 variables I want with each of the dataset? Could this work?

Thank you very much,

N.

Comment: Check `rbindlist` from `data.table` and its `fill` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from where you get `get_data` function but let's assume it gives you the data by passing name of an object to it. You could use the following -

```
listInd <- c("SDGFPALL","WHS4_154","WHS4_100","WHS4_106","TB_1","HIV_ARTCOVERAGE",
 "MDG_0000000013", "WSH_SANITATION_BASIC","BP_04","NCD_GLUC_04", 
 "TOBACCO_0000000192","WHS6_102","HWF_0001", "HRH_41","MH_6","SDGIHR2018","SDGIHR")

Labels <- c("year","region","country","gho","publishstate","value","worldbankincomegroup",
             "residenceareatype","datasource","agegroup","sex")


output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(listInd, function(x) {
    df <- get_data(x)
    df[setdiff(Labels, colnames(df))] <- NA
    return(df)
}))
```

However, as @nicola mentioned something like this with `data.table` should work as well

```
output <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(listInd, get_data), fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by doing this:

```
listInd <- list("SDGFPALL","WHS4_154","WHS4_100","WHS4_106","TB_1","HIV_ARTCOVERAGE","MDG_0000000013",
                "WSH_SANITATION_BASIC","BP_04","NCD_GLUC_04","TOBACCO_0000000192","WHS6_102","HWF_0001",
                "HWF_0006","SDGIHR2018","SDGIHR")

DataInd <- list()
for (k in 1:length(listInd)){
  print(k)
  Ind_name <- listInd[k]
  df <- get_data(Ind_name)
  DataInd[[length(DataInd)+1]] <- df
}

DataAll <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), DataInd)
```